# How To Run Matplotlib with CSV file containing headings

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file which I want matplotlib to create a bar chart for. However, the CSV has headings which are interfering. Here is the code I am using to try make matplotlib ignore the two headings so it can run the bar chart. I am also including an image of what the CSV file *actually* looks like versus what I'm trying to get matplotlib to read in[image: What the CSV actually looks like] [image: What the code is able to run]
The error I am getting when I run this code is "key error: COST"
How do I resolve this and allow the code to ignore the COUNTRY and COST headings

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('Europe.csv',sep=';')
price = df['COST']
countries = df['COUNTRY']
plt.style.use('grayscale') 
plt.bar( countries, price, label='Europe', color='red')
plt.ylabel('Price in US$')
plt.title('Cost of spotify premium per country')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

add `header=True` in your read_csv

Comment: "Passing a bool to header is invalid. "
TypeError: Passing a bool to header is invalid. Use header=None for no header or header=int or list-like of ints to specify the row(s) making up the column names. And also ```header = None``` gives me the same "key error: COST"

Comment: try `header=0` instead of the boolean. basically we're saying header is present in the 0th row

Comment: @Lucia Sorry, as i can see from the image you've shared, header is in 1st row, try `header=1`

Comment: seems to be same again

Comment: can you show the dataframe after you've read it with `df = pd.read_csv('Europe.csv',sep=';')` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226700/discussion-between-suhas-mucherla-and-lucia).

Comment: How about providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead?